# Liferay API call requires authenticated access

Tags: json, liferay, liferay-6, restful-authentication

We are making a Liferay API call via postman

...localhost:9080/api/jsonws/journalarticle/get-article/group-id/21333/article-id/21355

and that's the JSON result:

```
{"message": "Authenticated access required", "exception":"java.lang.SecurityException"}
```

We are using Liferay 6.2

**Do we have to add an additional paramter (like p_auth) ?**

**Or maybe we are doing something completely wrong without knowing it ?**

Answer (score 4):

Hi you don't need the p_auth from postman, just configure the tab authorization with a basic login using your liferay credential.

[image: postman auth]

for more info for calling  json service see the link https://www.liferay.com/it/web/tomas.polesovsky/blog/-/blogs/json-ws-security

Comment: Thanks, really smashing. Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this above the method in your `ServiceBaseImpl` class

```
@AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled=true)
```

For Example: The URL to this below for mine was
http://localhost:8080/[portlet-name]/api/jsonws/[service-entity]/get-remote-data

```
@AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled=true)
public String getRemoteData() {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try {

        obj.put("name", "sean");
        obj.put("age", 39);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return obj.toString();

}
```